# Pattern for saving an Entity then queuing to RabbitMQ

Tags: java, hibernate, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a timing issue with RabbitMQ. I have a Notification class that I am trying to save to the database from a web service running under tomcat, then queue that entity id to RabbitMQ for a consumer to pick up.

The problem is the message gets queued before the transaction completes so the consumer doesn't find the record.

I tried creating a separate transaction for just the saving part via the Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW but I get a Hibernate exception saying the following:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

Is there a pattern for this that people normally do to solve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We use this exact same pattern. I walked through the Spring code about 6 months  to ensure that the entity is saved first and then the message sent. It wasn't until recently that we started noticing that that might not be the case. From the documentation it seems that RabbitMQ should honor the database transaction. Perhaps this changed? Or maybe it never did and I just wasn't looking at the right places.

I'm assuming you have the RabbitMQTransactionManager bean setup?

Comment: Our consumer application is using a RabbitTransactionManager but the web application that saves to the DB and queues the message is just using a HibernateTransactionManager.

Comment: You need to show your configuration; the bottom line is you need to synchronize the rabbit transaction with the hibernate transaction (so it commits afterwards - e.g. wrap the db tx within a rabbit tx). Alternatively, simply defer the send until after the db transaction commits and don't use rabbit transactions at all.

Comment: I hate to make a global application config change for this one piece of code. I'm going to try flushing the hibernate session in this one case before I queue to rabbit. I know that sort of defeats the purpose of the transaction but I need a quick fix.  Long term I will try what you said @GaryRussell. Thanks!

Comment: @GaryRussell: Does the RabbitMQTransactionManager not do this synchronization with the database transactions out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment after mine; a simple solution might be to use a chained transaction manager, as described in [Dave Syer's JavaWorld Article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html).

Comment: Thank you! My next question was going to be how to wrap transaction managers since it didn't look like they support that out of the box.

Comment: For the publishing part I really don't need transactions except for the hibernate part. Is there a way to hook something in at the end of a transaction? Like onTransactionComplete  or something?

Comment: Nevermind I think I found it.    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter()
  {
   @Override
   public void afterCommit() 
   {
    queueNotificationForDelivery(notification);
   }
  });